# Make:middleware doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

In PHP Artisan when I put command:

```
php artisan make:middleware MiddlewareName
```

I get error like this:

```
[37;41m                                 [39;49m
[37;41m  [BadMethodCallException]       [39;49m
[37;41m  Method filter does not exist.  [39;49m
[37;41m                                 [39;49m
```

Could anyone explain me where the problem is?
Thank you

Comment: Are you using filters in routes? What version of Laravel are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're using a filter somewhere in your `routes.php` file. Remove it and then call the command again.

I believe filters were depreciated in `5.1` then removed in `5.2`.